# Delete digits between alphabets and comma in Python using re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like:

```
"January 1,1997"
"September 13,2000"
"January 1,1999"
"July 17,2000"
```

I want to remove numbers between comma and alphabets to get this:

```
"January,1997"
"September,2000"
"January,1999"
"July,2000"
```

I have searched many cases but none of them fits my situation.
My code is

```py
s = re.sub("\d{4}", "", s)
```

It does not work.

Comment: Something like `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\s+\d+,', r'\1,', text)` will do, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQXqhV/1). Or `re.sub(r'\b\s+\d+,', r',', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQXqhV/2)). There are lots of variations.

Comment: if you don't have to use re you could accomplish this with string slicing and the string find method and replace method. i.e  `x = x.replace(x[x.find(" "):x.find(",")],"")`  This would find everything between the space and the comma and remove it

Comment: That works!!! I am crying! It is so difficult for me to understand regex language. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @c-haworth: how about you turn the comment into the answer so that it can get accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use re you could accomplish this with string slicing and the string find method and replace method. i.e

```
x = x.replace(x[x.find(" "):x.find(",")],"")
```

This would find everything between the space and the comma and remove it.